# How to access data member of a class member function in main function?

Tags: c++, data-members

XX.HEADER

```
class ABC
{
public:
ABC(); // constructor
int XYZ(int );
int AA;
    int m
}
```

XX.CPP

```
Mat ABC::XYZ(int c)
{

AA = lambda;
return m;

}
```

MAIN.CPP

```
int main()
{
ABC myObject;
int labda = myObject.AA;

}
```

I want value of AA to be used in main function.

Suppose there is a header file with class definition and member function definition along with some public data members say

> AA.

Now in the cpp file for the header file with contain complete description of the header file along with function definition within the class. The data member

> AA
>
> contains some value within the member function. Now I want to use this data member 
>   AA
>
> in the main function. How can I do that. Right now I have just intialiazed in public: int AA and in function it is giving some integer value which is getting stored. Now I want to use this AA in main function.

Comment: Do you mean `int mainAA = myObject.AA;`?

Comment: yeah but its not working. I am successfully getting the result of the function " int mainfuntionresult = myObject.functionName()" but I also want to use AA which is one of the byproduct in the function "functionName()".

Comment: Your code is full of compile time errors. Please post real code.

Answer (score 0):

Post a smallest example of your problem using actual C++. But from that... i would not even call it pseudo-code, your problem might be that you need to call

```
myObject.XYZ(someInteger);
```

before you inspect `myObject.AA`.

Also, when you post some actual code, also state what exactly goes wrong. Is there a runtime error, is the value just unexpected, does your computer explode?